# Hreflang php code for getstore instead of getwebsite

Tags: hreflang

I am using the following code to generate the hreflang on my website:

```
<?php
$groupId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getGroupId();
$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groupId);

foreach ($collection as $store) {
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $store->getCurrentUrl()) . '" hreflang="' . $store->getCode() . '"/>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

This gives me the links exactly the way I want them but with the exception of 'default' store that appears as www.example.com/default/.

I would like to replace 'default' with 'en'. Is there a way to do it? I tried looking for the code but can't find it any where as most developers tend to use getWebsite instead of getstore. Would really appreciate if someone can help with the appropriate code in php that can be pasted in head.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach ($collection as $store) {
    $storeCode = $store->getCode() == 'default' ? 'en' : $store->getCode();
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $store->getCurrentUrl()) . '" hreflang="' . $storeCode . '"/>' . "\n";
}
```

Evaluate if `$store->getCode()` gives you `default`. If it does, set `$storeCode = 'en'`.

Comment: Thank you Vic, this works perfectly. The final code if someone is interested is:  <?php
$groupId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getGroupId();
$collection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $groupId);

foreach ($collection as $store) {
    $storeCode = $store->getCode() == 'default' ? 'en' : $store->getCode();
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $store->getCurrentUrl()) . '" hreflang="' . $storeCode . '"/>' . "\n";
}

?>

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accepted.